# Where "Big" comes before "Old"

Tags: word-property

Where does "big" come before "old"?

Where does "three" come before "triangular"?

Where does "intelligent" come before "studious"?

Where does "smooth" come before "pearly"?

Where does "beautiful" come before "green"?

There is one place (or rule, or method) where all these orders make sense. Can you find the key that satisfies all conditions?

Notes:

1. The alphabet is not a part of this puzzle. I know that four out of five pairs are in alphabetical order, but that's actually irrelevant.
2. I did not come up with this ordering system. It's much older than anyone on this forum and everyone here knows what it is - you might not be able to define it on the first try, but you use it all the time.
3. All of the orders follow the rule exactly. There is no stretching/bending of rules.

Comment: Using this system, is it possible that two words "rank" in the same position (i.e. neither comes before the other?)

Comment: @Hugh that's actually a really hard question to answer. Strictly using the source I did, the answer is "yes".

Comment: Well, it kind of is a rule, I would think. Perhaps you could make this an answer ;) ?

Comment: @EricTressler & Brandon_J — well that's clever...

Comment: @Hugh just our of curiosity, was that serious or sarcastic?

Comment: Serious. I've definitely encountered this "concept" but it didn't cross my mind. I truly think that this is a clever little riddle.

Comment: @Hugh OK, cool :) the dot-dot-dot and the discussion around this puzzle and one of its answers made me wonder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your question is referring to

> the usual order of adjectives/adverbs in English (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adjectives-order), which are given there as:

1. > opinion (*mysterious*)
2. > size (*giant*)
3. > physical quality (*flat*)
4. > shape (*rectangular*)
5. > age (*ancient*)
6. > colour (*black*)
7. > origin (*alien*)
8. > material (*???*)
9. > type (*monolithic*)
10. > purpose (*judging*)

Comment: For 8, "wooden" would be a possible value.  See also [this post on another SE site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order) which I was going to suggest that this was a duplicate of because i had just come from that site and was obviously still a bit confused.  :-)

Comment: No; it's unclear what the material is, but [wood seems unlikely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)#Meaning_of_the_monolith)

Comment: whoops, clearly I missed the theme of the examples.

Comment: That's okay, I was just trying to make the answer a little more interesting. For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure I saw the post you linked to, a few years ago. I did some further reading and eventually found [this article](http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20160908-the-language-rules-we-know-but-dont-know-we-know), which stuck with me as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> the order in which a baby will learn these words?

It does fit pretty nicely, however it may not be the expected answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand - could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. No, the rule isn't anything that I've created. It's been around for longer than I've been alive.

Comment: @Brandon_J Edited again :)

Comment: I like this idea (upvote), but it's not what I was looking for. I've updated my post with a contradictory pair of words. Very creative solution, though!

Comment: @Brandon_J Thanks! I've also upvoted your question as it seems to be quite far-reaching given the amount of reasonable yet wrong answers.

Answer (score 2):

At a stretch it could be...

> A dictionary with the Pe page ripped out and placed at the end.

Comment: Haha good one - but no stretching or tearing is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution!

> In the alphabet. B comes before O, th comes before tr, I comes before S and S comes before P.

Comment: Unfortunately, P comes before S in the alphabet :) Good try, though!

Comment: Sorry. Oops, I was so happy!

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer may be:

> `Time.` One chronologically can come before the other.
>  It does not say that it *always* has to come before, since it uses *"where does"* instead of *"what always"*. Therefore, I believe that `time` is a possible answer.

Where does "big" come before "old"?

> When you are old, you shrink. A person is often a couple inches shorter (or more) when they are very old, largely due to spinal compression from gravity along with loss of bone density. So, you are bigger when you are younger.

Where does "three" come before "triangular"?

> You need 3 sides first before you can have a triangle.

Where does "intelligent" come before "studious"?

> If you are intelligent, it can follow that you are also studious, as you are more likely to study a lot. It does often follow that the person is studious when they are intelligent.

Where does "smooth" come before "pearly"?

> In order to be considered pearly, you must first be smooth. While is is possible to be smooth and not pearly, it is unlikely to be considered pearly if it is not smooth first.

Update:

You edited your question with a new pair.

Where does "beautiful" come before "green"?

> You changed the terms of this question. Please don't change a question which invalidates existing answers. ***That said, I can still follow the rule:***
>  
>  A picked flower. A picked flower in a vase must first be beautiful if it is to remain green. If the flower is ugly, it will not be green as it will be thrown in the trash and become brown.

Comment: Another good possibility (upvote) - but not what I'm looking for. I should probably add some new pairs.

Comment: Haha! Great :) Yes may not be your original intent but based on what currently exists in the question I believe my answer is possible :)

Comment: There we go - I've invalidated your answer :)

Comment: @Brandon_J One of the unspoken rules on this site is *Please don't change a question which invalidates existing answers. It is considered rude.* Thanks! :)

Comment: I suppose it's spoken now :) I only did it to narrow down possible answers and justify explaining why your answers aren't what I was looking for. Should I rollback?

Comment: @Riddler You may also see the edit as an additional hint. In any case, both your answer and mine are debatable albeit creative.

Comment: @Riddler yeah, sort of in the vein in which you added the hint that said that Harry's last name was Nabersen in your Eyebright puzzle - that invalidated my answer, but was a good hint.

Comment: @Brandon_J you can keep it as is since I was able to save my answer with a further solution following the same rule. :)

Comment: @Brandon_J *that's not the same because I said in mine that all the info to solve was already in my riddle. Your answer asking Harry's last name was info that was not in the riddle, so it could not have been the answer.*

Comment: @Brandon_J A *picked* flower is already beautiful when picked. ;)

Comment: And it's already green, as well. You have a kind of "if" statement, not a strictly time-based statement.

Comment: @Brandon_J I used *picked flower* because it is in reference to the *future* aka *time*... if not beautiful then not green ;)

Comment: and if not green, then not beautiful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89537/discussion-between-brandon-j-and-riddler). @Riddler